# element overlaying each other and hidding them

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created few elements but the render is making one showing below the other. In the image below, you will see that I have a toggle below the 3 tiles instead of being place before.

[image]

that should look like the image below:

[image]

below is the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import PriceCard from '../components/materialdesign/PriceCard';
import { Col, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import PriceInfo from '../config/PriceInfo';
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import './HowItWorks.css';

class HowItWorks extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            toggle: false
        };
        
        this.toggleState = this.toggleState.bind(this);
    }
        
    toggleState(){
        this.setState({
            toggle: !this.state.toggle
        });
    }
    
    render() {

        const Switch = 
            <form className="switch-field">
                <div className="switch-field-element">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="switch_left"
                        name="switchToggle"
                        value={TextContents.CreditsBundle}
                        onChange={this.toggleState}
                        checked={!this.state.toggle}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="switch_left">{TextContents.CreditsBundle}</label>
                </div>
                
                <div className="switch-field-element">
                    <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="switch_right"
                        name="switchToggle"
                        value={TextContents.SubscriptionsBundle}
                        onChange={this.toggleState}
                        checked={this.state.toggle}
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="switch_right">{TextContents.SubscriptionsBundle}</label>
                </div>
            </form>

        const CreditBundles = 
                <div className="hiw-price-info-container">
                    <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1} price={PriceInfo.Credits1.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Credits1.values.credits} percent={PriceInfo.Credits1.values.percentage} buttontext={TextContents.BuyCreditsBtn}/>
                    <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw2} price={PriceInfo.Credits2.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Credits2.values.credits} percent={PriceInfo.Credits2.values.percentage} buttontext={TextContents.BuyCreditsBtn}/>
                    <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw2} price={PriceInfo.Credits3.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Credits3.values.credits} percent={PriceInfo.Credits3.values.percentage} buttontext={TextContents.BuyCreditsBtn}/>
                </div>

        const Subscription =                 
                <div className="hiw-price-info-container">
                <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1} price={PriceInfo.Subscription1.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Subscription1.values.credits} buttontext={TextContents.SubscribeBtn}/>
                <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1}price={PriceInfo.Subscription2.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Subscription2.values.credits} buttontext={TextContents.SubscribeBtn}/>
                <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1} price={PriceInfo.Subscription3.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Subscription3.values.credits} buttontext={TextContents.SubscribeBtn}/>
                </div>

        return (
            <div className="hiw-container">
                <h1> {TextContents.HowItWorksTitle} </h1>
                <p> {TextContents.VillagePassport} </p>
                {Switch}
                {!this.state.toggle && CreditBundles}
                {this.state.toggle && Subscription}
                
            </div>
        );
    }
    
}

export default HowItWorks;
```

and the css :

```
:root {
  --village-selector-height: 80px;
  --village-color-blue: #14cff0;
}

.hiw-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom:5rem;
    width: 70%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.hiw-container h1{
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;  
}

.hiw-container h2{
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.58;
    letter-spacing: -0.8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.hiw-container p{
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #616161;
}

.hiw-price-info-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 500px;
}


.switch-field {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

.switch-field-element {
  position: relative;
  height: 80px;

}

.switch-field-element:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: -60px;
}
  
  
  .switch-field input {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .switch-field label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 80px;
    background-color:#f4f7f8;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .1s;
    color: #dfdfdf;
    user-select: none;
    border-radius: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  }

  .switch-field label::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 8px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid white;
    border-right: 2px solid white;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .switch-field input:checked + label {
    background-color: var(--village-color-blue);
    border-color: var(--village-color-blue);
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 20px -2px rgba(black, .1);
  }
  
  .switch-field label:first-of-type {
    padding-right: 80px;
  }

  .switch-field label:first-of-type::before {
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .switch-field label:first-of-type::after {
    right: 12px;
    top: 9px;
  }
  
  .switch-field label:last-of-type {
    padding-left: 80px;
  }

  .switch-field label:last-of-type::before {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  .switch-field label:last-of-type::after {
    left: 12px;
    top: 9px;
  }

/* tablet, ipad  version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){

    .hiw-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom:5rem;
        width: 50%;
    }

}

/* mobile version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (max-width: 600px) {

    .hiw-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom:5rem;
        width: 70%;
    }

}
```

Any idea how to fix it with breaking the toggle switch experience ?

Thanks

Comment: please post a codesandbox for thi.s without knowing what the other elements are, we cant help you with this

Comment: The problem seems to be stemming from `position: absolute;` style on `.switch-field` in the `CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using bootstrap then why you are not using row and columns I can see you are using custom class for structuring which is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Z-index might be overwritten, try:

```
z-index: 1 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is related to CSS

```
 .hiw-price-info-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 500px;
        position:relative;
    }
```